# ¿Cómo realizar join not exist en mongodb?

Tags: sql, mongodb

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL y quiero llevarla a mongo (estoy realizando unas pruebas, entiendo que en mongodb se debería evitar los joins)

```
SELECT[CodigoNodo]  FROM HistoricoTransformadores ht   where IdentificadorEmpresa=1   and ht.FechaMesOperacion=N'07-01-2020'   and not exists(Select 1 from Afectaciones af   where IdentificadorEmpresa=1   and ht.CodigoNodo=af.CodigoNodo   and af.FechaUltimoReporte=N'07-01-2020');
```

He estado tratando de hacer esto usando $lookup pero no he tenido suerte:

```
db.getCollection("HistoricoTransformadores").aggregate(
[
    { 
        "$lookup" : { 
            "from" : "Afectaciones", 
            "let" : { 
                "codNodo" : "$CodigoNodo"
            }, 
            "pipeline" : [
                { 
                    "$match" : { 
                        "$expr" : { 
                            "$and" : [
                                { 
                                    "$eq" : [
                                        "$IdentificadorEmpresa", 
                                        1.0
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                { 
                                    "$eq" : [
                                        "$$codNodo", 
                                        "$CodigoNodo"
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                { 
                                    "$eq" : [
                                        "$FechaUltimoReporte", 
                                        ISODate("2020-07-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ], 
            "as" : "NodosAfectados"
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$match" : { 
            "NodosAfectados.CodigoNodo" : { 
                "$exists" : false
            }
        }
    }
], 
{ 
    "allowDiskUse" : false
}
```

);

el problema esta cuando uso agrego el filtro:

"$eq" : ["$FechaUltimoReporte", SODate("2020-07-01T00:00:00.000+0000")]

En es caso no me trae información.

Comment: ***entiendo que en mongodb se debería evitar los joins*** No es que se deberían evitar, es que el concepto de **JOIN** se maneja diferente en MongoDB. Tal vez hayas oído hablar de agregación o de map-reduce, sin embargo, si el modelado de datos no es bueno, hacer uso de estas herramientas naturales de MongoDB puede llegar a ser muy complicado. Lo que siempre recomiendo es que no se compare una forma de hacer las cosas (SQL) con otra forma (noSQL).

Comment: Por otro lado la condición `"$eq" : ["$FechaUltimoReporte", ISODate("2020-07-01T00:00:00.000+0000")]` dice que traiga reportes con esa fecha, hora, minuto, segundo y milisegundo. Es lógico que no te traiga ningún resultado si no existe un reporte con esa fecha tan específica. Debes manejar rangos de fechas, recuerda que `ISODate` es al fin y al cabo un valor entero, piensa en eso y seguro hallarás la forma de traer los reportes, yo haría uso de `$lte` en vez de `$eq`. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que estás usando el operador [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/index.html) en un campo de fecha ([`ISODate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/index.html#date)). Por lo cual estás pidiendo documentos que cumplan un criterio demasiado específico, ya que `ISODate` almacena la cantidad de milisegundos transcurridos desde la [fecha Unix](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix).

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es usar un rango de fechas, y para decirle a MongoDB que busque en un rango de fechas tenemos varias opciones.

Por ejemplo, podemos indicar la fecha del reporte como un rango si utilizamos el operador [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/index.html) y le pasamos como argumento dos comparaciones contra fechas (inicial y final) utilizando los operadores [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) y [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lte/). Todos los documentos que se encuentren dentro de ese rango serán devueltos en la consulta.

Por ejemplo:

```js
{ 
  "$and" : [
    {
      $gte: [
        "$FechaUltimoReporte", 
        ISODate("2020-07-01T00:00:00.000+0000") // <- fecha inicial
      ]
    },
    {
      $lte: [
        "$FechaUltimoReporte", 
        ISODate("2020-07-01T23:59:59.999+0000") // <- fecha final
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

De esta forma cualquier documento que contenga un valor (en el campo solicitado) dentro del rango de búsqueda será devuelto en nuestra consulta.

Podemos ver un ejemplo de esta implementación en el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pn3XXMILEIY).